# Implement GetEnumerator() in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a few classes that one of them is inheriting from IEnumerable in mvc application. 
When i am passing the model i am getting the exception "The method or operation is not implemented."
Non of my searches over the web was as my infrastructure

Those classes belong to the dll

```
public class Raflle : Base
    {
        public string RaflleNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime RaflleDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsNear { get; set; }
    }

public class Raflles : IEnumerable<Raflle>
    {
        public List<Raflle> TList { get; private set; }

        public Raflles()
        {
            TList = new List<Raflle>();
        }
        public void Add(Raflle item)
        {
            TList.Add(item);
        }

        public IEnumerator<Raflle> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This class is in the mvc application

```
 public class RafllesModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string RaflleNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime RaflleDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsNear { get; set; }
    }



public class RafllesController : Controller
    {
        MainLogic ml = new MainLogic();
        //
        // GET: /Raflles/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var raffles = ml.GetRaflles();
            IEnumerable<RafllesModel> rafflesModel;
            rafflesModel = raffles.Select(x => new RafllesModel 
            { 
                ID = x.ID, 
                RaflleNumber = x.RaflleNumber, 
                RaflleDate = x.RaflleDate, 
                IsNear = x.IsNear 
            });
            return View(rafflesModel);
        }
    }
```

And of course that i want the view to act like :

```
@model IEnumerable<BackOffice.Models.RafllesModel>
```

I am guessing that there are a few things that i am doing wrong, i would like to know what the GetEnumerator() supposed to do.

Thank you
Danny

Comment: You have not implemented methods pertaining to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Why oh why do you need to create your own enumerable? Just use IEnumerable<Raflle> !! (BTW - Raflle should be raffle?!)

Comment: I know about the missspelling . I didn't want to create my own. But as i inherited from ienumerable i had to implement the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ml.GetRaflles(); returns an instance of the Raffles class: You can return the enumerator of the list:

```
   public IEnumerator<Raflle> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return TList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
```

Alternatively, since List is a public property, you could skip the implementation, and use the List directly: rafflesModel = raffles.**TList**.Select( ..el

```
rafflesModel = raffles.TList.Select(x => new RafllesModel 
            { 
                ID = x.ID, 
                RaflleNumber = x.RaflleNumber, 
                RaflleDate = x.RaflleDate, 
                IsNear = x.IsNear 
            });
```